# How to use boolean mask arrays with NumPy using PythonKit in Swift

Tags: python, ios, swift, numpy, open3d

I have the following Python code:

```
print("Cluster connected triangles")

with o3d.utility.VerbosityContextManager(
        o3d.utility.VerbosityLevel.Debug) as cm:
    triangle_clusters, cluster_n_triangles, cluster_area = (
        mesh.cluster_connected_triangles())
triangle_clusters = np.asarray(triangle_clusters)
cluster_n_triangles = np.asarray(cluster_n_triangles)
cluster_area = np.asarray(cluster_area)

print("Get mesh with small clusters removed")

mesh_1 = copy.deepcopy(mesh)
largest_cluster_idx = cluster_n_triangles.argmax()
triangles_to_remove = triangle_clusters != largest_cluster_idx
mesh_1.remove_triangles_by_mask(triangles_to_remove)
```

which i am trying to adapt in Swift (PythonKit)

```
let np = Python.import("numpy")

let clusters = mesh.cluster_connected_triangles()
let triangle_clusters = np.asarray(clusters[0])
let cluster_n_triangles = np.asarray(clusters[1])
let cluster_area = np.asarray(clusters[2])
let largest_cluster_idx = cluster_n_triangles.argmax()
let triangles_to_remove = (triangle_clusters != largest_cluster_idx).  // ERROR: Ambiguous use of operator '!='
let largestCluster = mesh.remove_triangles_by_mask(triangles_to_remove)
```

can someone please help me convert this Python line :
`triangles_to_remove = triangle_clusters != largest_cluster_idx` in Swift/PythonKit

in other words:
what is the PythonKit/Swift syntax for creating boolean mask arrays?

Comment: since it's Python code, all Swift variables are PythonObject. agreed on naming standards, but this is a special case for Python-related code, i think it makes sense to leave it as is for the sake of Swift-Python parallelism for the question readability sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to wrap the code in PythonObject:

```
print("Clustering...")

let clusters = mesh.cluster_connected_triangles()
let triangle_clusters = np.asarray(clusters[0])
let cluster_n_triangles = np.asarray(clusters[1])
let cluster_area = np.asarray(clusters[2])
let largest_cluster_idx = cluster_n_triangles.argmax()

print("\(mesh) : with \(cluster_n_triangles.count) clusters.")
print("Largest cluster : \(cluster_n_triangles[largest_cluster_idx]) triangles.")

//THIS!
let triangles_to_remove = PythonObject(triangle_clusters != largest_cluster_idx)

mesh.remove_triangles_by_mask(triangles_to_remove)
mesh.remove_unreferenced_vertices()

print("Cluster Result: \(mesh)")
```